# Perform complex join and subquery in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to generate all member statement which are in almost 8 tables like
1. payments
2. loan
3. purchase
4. receive

want to generate  report by it's type currently I used separate function for all of them is it possible to do it in one query. please consider I want report like this
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzjDA.png)

this are my table I didn't showed the detail but actual database is almost the same
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaiCw.png)

```
    public function exportAllPayments($member_id=0,$type='',$from_date='',$to_date='')
{
      $query=$this->leftjoin('members','members.id','payments.member_id')
                ->leftjoin('transactions','payments.payable_transaction','transactions.id')
                ->leftjoin('accounts','transactions.account_id','accounts.id')
                ->selectRaw("payments.id as id,members.name as Name,payments.rate as Rate,payments.discount as Discount,payments.type as Payment_type,payments.description as Description, transactions.amount*-1 as amount,transactions.unit as currency,accounts.name as Account,date_format(from_unixtime(payments.date),'%b %d, %Y') as Date")
                ->orderBy('members.id');
     if($type && $type !='')
     $query =$query->where('payments.type',$type);

    if($member_id && $member_id !=0)
     $query =$query->where('members.id',$member_id);

    if($from_date && $from_date !='')
     $query =$query->where('payments.date','>=',$from_date);

     if($to_date && $to_date !='')
     $query =$query->where('payments.date','<=',$to_date);


     return $query->get();
}
     $payments = $this->payment->exportAllPayments($member->id,'',$from_date,$to_date);
           foreach ($payments as $key => $payment) {
            array_push($data, [
            'type'              =>'pay',
            'member_name'       =>$member->name,
            'Payment_type'      =>$payment->Payment_type,
            'Amount'            =>$payment->amount,
            'currency'          =>$payment->currency,
            'Rate'              =>$payment->Rate,
            'Account'           =>$payment->Account,
            'Date'              =>$payment->Date
            ]); 

        }
```

Comment: Read the documentation for Eloquent Relationships, and the whereHas method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I already read but I want them all in one query, thank you by the way

Comment: Yes, then you would write one query like: $member->whereHas(['accout', function($q){$q->where('Something);}])->whereHas(['payment', function($q){ $->where('something_else'); }])->get()

Comment: It wouldn't strictly be one query but you can get the information in one go with Eloquent. Can you add your code to show how you're currently doing this (not an image).

Comment: ok here is one of those table that I want to get report from and push the result in an array

Comment: Please can you copy and paste your code instead of adding an image? Otherwise,  people won't be able to try and replicate your problem without manually writing out what's in the image.